# Implementing Remember me using php

Tags: php, cookies

I don't know what is going wrong in my code.I have already implemented login and signup using ajax calls. Now, I am trying to implement remember me using cookies in php. My code for that goes like this

```
<?php require 'database.php';
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST["login"])) {
    #$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog_samples");
    $sql = "Select * from login where Username = '" . $_POST["member_name"] . "' and Password = '" . ($_POST["member_password"]) . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($user) {

            if(!empty($_POST["remember"])) {
                setcookie ("member_login",$_POST["member_name"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                setcookie ("member_password",$_POST["member_password"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
            } else {
                if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) {
                    setcookie ("member_login","");
                }
                if(isset($_COOKIE["member_password"])) {
                    setcookie ("member_password","");
                }
            }
            header("location:private.php");
    }
}
?>  


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="form-body-login col-md-6 col-xs-6">

   <form class="Login" method="post" action="private.php">
     <div class="row buttons">
       <div type="submit" class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 login">Login</div>
       <div type="submit" class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 sign_up">Sign up</div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="login_body">
       <div class="row user_name">
         <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x col-md-1 col-xs-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <input type="text" class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 username" id="username_login" placeholder="abc@xyz.com" name="member_name" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { echo $_COOKIE["member_login"]; } ?>" />
       </div>
     <div class="row pwd">
       <i class="fa fa-key fa-2x col-md-1 col-xs-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <input type="password" class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 password" id="password_login" placeholder="Password" name="member_password" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_password"])) { echo $_COOKIE["member_password"]; } ?>"/>
     </div>
        <div class="row remember col-md-11 col-xs-11">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="autologin" id="checkbox" name="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { ?> checked <?php } ?>/> Remember Me </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-md-11 col-xs-11">
          <button type="submit" id="button" name="login">Login</button>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-body-signup">
     <div class="row username_signup">
     <input type="text" id="username_signup" class="col-md-10" placeholder="Enter user name"/>
     </div>
       <div class="row password_signup">
         <input type="password" id="password_signup" class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" placeholder="Enter password here" />
       </div>
       <div class="row phone">
         <input type="text" id="phone" class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" placeholder="enter phone number" />
       </div>

     <div class="row signup_button">
       <button type="submit" id="check">Create New User</button>
     </div>
          </div>
   </form>


</div>   
  </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

On login or signup, after doing all the necessary validations, the page directs to private.php. That page looks something like this:

```
<?php
echo"Hello";
session_start();
#$_SESSION["member_id"] = "";
session_destroy();
#header("Location: ./");
?>
```

But somehow, the cookies are not getting stored if I check the remember me check box.
I am doing this for the first time and don't really know what is going wrong here.

Comment: 1st of all, your code isn't safe : you should **really** consider using [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will help [Preventing SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). And you should not store plain-text password, neither store them in cookie -> refer to `password_hash` -> [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and `password_verify` [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: That I have done in my original code. I have only having issues in the remember functionality. Thanks anyway @OldPadawan

Comment: plus that you can't access `$_COOKIE["member_login"]` after setting it -> `Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for.` as per the [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: where do i have to add this member_login? In the form?

Answer (score 0):

set_cookie does not update the $_COOKIE super global array in my experience until after the next page load. So if you're saving information to cookies, remember that you also need to add it manually to $_COOKIE at the same time so you'll need to add:

```
$_COOKIE['member_login'] = $_POST['member_login'];
```

For example, if you want to check what the value is for the cookie without reloading the script.

Here's an example of what the code should look like:

```
if($user) {
    if(!empty($_POST["remember"])) {
        setcookie ("member_login",$_POST["member_name"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        $_COOKIE['member_login'] = $_POST['member_login'];      // This is new
        setcookie ("member_password",$_POST["member_password"],time()+ (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        $_COOKIE['member_password'] = $_POST['member_password'];        // This is new
    } else {
        if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) {
            setcookie ("member_login","");
            $_COOKIE['member_login'] = '';      // This is new
        }
        if(isset($_COOKIE["member_password"])) {
            setcookie ("member_password","");
            $_COOKIE['member_password'] = '';       // This is new
        }
    }
    header("location:private.php");
}
```

That being said, @OldPadawan has a point that you really should sanitize the data being submitted via the form, or you'll leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks and XSS attacks.

It may also be easier in the future if you wrap both `set_cookie` and setting the super-global $_COOKIE into a complete function like this:

```
function set_inline_accessible_cookie( $key, $value, $exp = null ) {
    if ( is_null( $exp ) || ! is_numeric( $exp ) ) {
        $exp = time() + ( 86400 * 30 );
    }
    $_COOKIE[ $key ] = $value;
    return setcookie( $key, $value, $exp, '/' );
}
```

Comment: where should I add member_login? @bdb.jack

Comment: @aayushi I've updated the answer to be a little more specific

Comment: somehow, if i check 'remember me', then I am being redirected to the private.php page.After that, I press the back button in my browser. So, the username stays, but not the password. @bdb.jack

Comment: And If I refresh the page, then nothing is there anymore in any of the fields.

Comment: This is such bad practice. Don't **EVER** put passwords, hashed or not, in cookies

Answer (score 0):

> `Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for.` according to the [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

For what you want to achieve, (IMHO) best would be :

- check against DB **after you sanitize user's data**
- set (all) cookie(s)
- redirect to `private.php` (cookie will be active then)
- check cookie(s) on that page to grant/refuse access

In your case : $sql -> $result -> $user -> setcookies (all at once) -> redirect. Below a working example (page is self-called -> 'remember-me.php'):

```
<?php
// only example, adapt to your needs
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//print_r($_COOKIE); // only for checking if needed

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

$member_name = $_POST['member_name'];
$remember_me = $_POST['remember_me'];

//print_r($_POST); // only for checking if needed

if(isset($remember_me)) {

setcookie("member_login", $member_name);
setcookie("remember_me", 1);

echo"We will remember you next time! <a href=\"remember-me.php\">Check this !</a>"; // or redirect to private.php without output before

 }
}

?>
<form method="post" action="remember-me.php">
    <p><input type="text" id="member_name" name="member_name" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { echo $_COOKIE["member_login"]; } ?>" /></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" name="remember_me" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["remember_me"])) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/> Remember Me </label></p>
    <p><input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login" /></p>
</form>
```

**EDIT 2** -> to adapt to your initial question (after chat and further inquiry - below is raw code example) :

```
<?php
session_start();
require'database.php';

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
// connect to DB
$sql = " xxxx "; // make query
if($user) { // if results

    $member_name = $_POST['member_name']; // or return from DB row, up to you
    $remember_me = $_POST['remember_me'];

    if(isset($remember_me)) {

    setcookie("member_login", $member_name);
    setcookie("remember_me", 1);
    }
    // could use session here if needed and no output before
    header("location:private.php");
   }
  }
?>
```

> **NOT ONLY** on one page, but on all of them (including the one you show), you should **really** consider using [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will help [Preventing SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

and also :

> **never ever** use/store plain-text password, use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: I added a `In your case` line in answer

Comment: as far as I understand, the redirection is done using header location in cookies.Am i right? @OldPadawan

Comment: as you won't be able to check cookie values on the same page, you set it/them and redirect immediately yes (EDIT: make sure no output before or you'll get warned !)

Comment: so,in my case I have already directed them to private.php. In that php page, if I do header("Location: ./"), then my login signup buttons stop working, so I commented that line. But of no use for remember me.

Comment: when user want to log in, don't you ask for `login + pwd + remember me` ? if not, should be done at same time though -> if access granted, cookies are set and redirect, if not -> error

Comment: if i do this, and refresh the page, then also the input fields are not getting populated with the values.Why is this happening? @OldPadawan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143076/discussion-between-oldpadawan-and-aayushi).